# Accidentally installed two versions of git

Tags: git, installation, uninstall, homebrew

I originally had git installed via Homebrew, but on this machine I forgot to setup the bash completion. So when I attempted to download the git source I accidentally installed a second version of git (1.7.3) which overrode 1.8.0.

Obviously I should've been more careful. So, I attempted to uninstall that version of git in hopes the version installed with Homebrew would just work, but it's not.

So question is, how do I uninstall all versions of git, and then re-install the latest version with Homebrew?

I tried

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/git
rm /etc/paths.d/git
```

But after the first line, I just got: No such file or directory

I also uninstalled git through brew and then reinstalled it, but when I do:

```
git --version
```

I get nothing. :/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your $PATH to see if it's correct set? Remember `/usr/local/bin` should come before `/usr/bin` when using Homebrew (or whatever path you have set for your installation of Homebrew.)

Example: (this should be in your `.profile` file, or `.zprofile` if you use Zsh)

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

This way, the Git version installed via Homebrew should be detected first before any system installations.

But we can easily debug this, if you type the following command into your shell and post the output:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. After checking and setting my $PATH I was able to successfully reinstall git and get rid of all other versions.